# React-Router: How to test href of a rendered Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, react-router

I have a React component that renders a `<Link/>`.

```
render: function () {
    var record = this.props.record;
    return (
        <Link to="record.detail" params={{id:record.id}}>
            <div>ID: {record.id}</div>
            <div>Name: {record.name}</div>
            <div>Status: {record.status}</div>
        </Link>
    );
}
```

I can easily obtain the rendered `<a/>`, but I'm not sure how to test that the href was built properly.

```
function mockRecordListItem(record) {
    return stubRouterContext(require('./RecordListItem.jsx'), {record: record});
}
it('should handle click', function () {
    let record = {id: 2, name: 'test', status: 'completed'};
    var RecordListItem = mockRecordListItem(record);
    let item = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<RecordListItem/>);

    let a = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(item, 'a');
    expect(a);

    // TODO: inspect href?
    expect(/* something */).to.equal('/records/2');
});
```

Notes: The [stubRouterContext](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v0.13.3/docs/guides/testing.md) is necessary in React-Router v0.13.3 to mock the `<Link/>` correctly.

### Edit:

Thanks to [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30332776/317951) for suggesting `a.getDOMNode().getAttribute('href')`. Unfortunately when I run the test, the result is `null`. I expect this has to do with the way `stubRouterContext` is mocking the `<Link/>`, but how to 'fix' is still TBD...

Comment: Yeah. See my answer which is the accepted one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30333190/317951

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. This simply took some digging into the [`stubRouterContext`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/testing.md) that I already had.

The third constructor argument, `stubs`, is what I needed to pass in, overriding the default `makeHref` function.

Working example:

```
function mockRecordListItem(record, stubs) {
    return stubRouterContext(require('./RecordListItem.jsx'), {record: record}, stubs);
}
it('should handle click', function () {
    let record = {id: 2, name: 'test', status: 'completed'};
    let expectedRoute = '/records/2';
    let RecordListItem = mockRecordListItem(record, {
        makeHref: function () {
            return expectedRoute;
        }
    });
    let item = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<RecordListItem/>);
    let a = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(item, 'a');
    expect(a);

    let href = a.getDOMNode().getAttribute('href');
    expect(href).to.equal(expectedRoute);
});
```

It was right there in front of me the whole time.

Comment: I'm not using jest. I'm using mocha / istanbul.

Answer (score 8):

I use jest and enzyme for testing. For Link from Route I use Memory Router from their official documentation https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing

I needed to check href of the final constructed link. This is my suggestion:

MovieCard.js:

```
export function MovieCard(props) {
  const { id, type } = props;
  return (
    <Link to={`/${type}/${id}`} className={css.card} />
  )
};
```

MovieCard.test.js (I skip imports here):

```
const id= 111;
const type= "movie";

test("constructs link for router", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <MovieCard type={type} id={id}/>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find('[href="/movie/111"]').length).toBe(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `a.getDOMNode()` to get the `a` component's DOM node and then use regular DOM node methods on it. In this case, `getAttribute('href')` will return the value of the `href` attribute:

```
let a = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(item, 'a');
let domNode = a.getDOMNode();

expect(domNode.getAttribute('href')).to.equal('/records/2');
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems correct, but when I execute the test, `getAttribute('href')` returns `null`. I expect this probably has something to do with `stubRouterContext`. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: FWIW, an easy way to see what's been rendered is `console.log(domNode.outerHTML)`.

Comment: I downvoted because this method doesn't actually work. The href will be `undefined` if you don't stub React Router.